# How to test an apps that uses UIActivityViewController share data?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

My guess is to have 2 physical devices to test this. Any easier way to do this?

Also, to test sharing data via SMS, this would mean 2 physical devices with data support (i.e. service)?

Comment: You can use iMessages over any WiFi network - no need for cellular service. Just set up a few spare iCloud accounts for test devices. I can usually test with only one device, just sending messages to myself, but sometimes it's handy having two.

Comment: Have you found a way to do it? I have two devices but sharing does not work correctly: When I click on the shared link (e.g. in iMessage) it tries to open it but shows an error "You need a newer version of %APPNAME% to open this, but the required version couldn't be found in the App Store. [...]" Help appreciated!